# How to solve this query statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please, help me solve this SQL statement. I spent several days with this issue.

I use SQL Server 2012.

Level = N'First'   --I use Unicode text

```
SELECT ss.id,
       ss.SID,
       CONCAT(CONCAT(ss.Name, ' '), ss.Surname) AS Sname,
       ss.Level,
       pp.PID,
       CONCAT(CONCAT(pp.Name1, ' '), pp.Name2) AS Pname,
       ss.Chk
FROM tb_student1 AS ss,
     tb_parent AS pp
WHERE ss.ParentID = pp.PID
  AND ss.Level = N'First'
  AND ss.Chk = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT st.SID
                         FROM (SELECT s.id,
                                      s.SID,
                                      CONCAT(CONCAT(s.Name, ' '), s.Surname) AS Sname,
                                      p.PID,
                                      CONCAT(CONCAT(p.Name1, ' '), p.Name2) AS Pname,
                                      s.Chk
                               FROM tb_student1 AS s,
                                    tb_parent AS p
                               WHERE s.ParentID = p.PID
                                 AND s.Level = N'First'
                                 AND s.Chk = 1) AS st ,
                              (SELECT * FROM tb_New_Reg AS r) AS rnp
                         WHERE st.SID = rnp.SID
                           AND rnp.ClassID = 'C104'
                           AND rnp.Year = '2018-2019'
                           AND rnp.Term = 'Jan'
                           AND rnp.Level = N'First'
                           AND st.Chk = 1);
```

If I use (...and ss.SID not exists ...) error here. If I use (...and not exists ....) return null

The first query contains 11 rows, the subquery contain 6 rows

How to solve with it?

Comment: Table data and expected results will help your post.

Comment: You appear to be trying to use an `EXISTS` like an `IN`, but then your `EXISTS` returns 3 columns and doesn't have a lateral join? Also it's time to come join the rest of us and stop using syntax that's been outdated for 27 years: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I want to value NOT EXISTS  in subquery. I tried NOT IN but error introduce with EXISTS

Comment: Please, help me I spend many days with only  this case.

Comment: Are the two queries supposed to correlate?

Comment: SID is the same Value and other values are independent

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The independent values I put in '...' marked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        ss.id, ss.SID,
        CONCAT(CONCAT(ss.Name, ' '), ss.Surname) AS Sname,
        ss.Level, pp.PID,
        CONCAT(CONCAT(pp.Name1, ' '), pp.Name2) AS Pname,
        ss.Chk
    FROM tb_student1 AS ss INNER JOIN tb_parent AS pp ON ss.ParentID = pp.PID
    WHERE ss.Level = N'First' AND ss.Chk = 1
)
SELECT * FROM data AS s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tb_New_Reg AS rnp
    WHERE s.SID = rnp.SID
        AND rnp.ClassID = 'C104'
        AND rnp.Year = '2018-2019'
        AND rnp.Term = 'Jan'
        AND rnp.Level = N'First'
);
```

I think this is along the lines of what you're looking for. I did break out your main query into a CTE thinking I would be duplicating that same query inside the subquery. It turns out that probably wasn't really necessary but I've left it that way.

I presume that your attempt failed because the inner query is searching across the entire table when what you really intended was to narrow that search to a matching `SID` from the outer query. You'll probably find it useful to look up *correlated subquery* for better understanding of the concept.

Comment: That is well done. @shawnt00, Billion thanks I have done this with you minefulness.

Comment: I also done with  join style by given comment above by @Larnu. Billion thank to all.